# Questions about the superfactorial function.

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, asymptotics

N superfactorial or $n\$$ is defined as -
$$n\$=\prod_{k=1}^n k!$$ 
Then is there any asymptotic formula for this?

Are there any infinite series , integrals related to this function? 
Is there a closed form of a derivative of this function?

Comment: This is directly related to the Barnes-G function: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BarnesG-Function.html